# Is it possible to send a push notification from SFMC to a Web App?

Tags: marketing-cloud, push

We would like to be able to send push notifications from SFMC to Android, iOS, and Web clients (ReactJS).  We have achieved the mobile apps using the SDK but would like to add the functionality to our web app.

Does anyone have experience of doing this or even know if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to achieve this at the moment, but if you want to get into the nuts and bolts, all Marketing Cloud basically does is store FCM tokens so you can break apart apart the Java sdk to get the endpoints being used then leverage that to build a basic PWA notification handler. It's far from perfect but we have it working with a client :)
Doug

Comment: Hello @Doug, do you have more details or tips to give about this? It would really help