# How to allow for both mobile push notifications and web app notifications in SFMC and synchronise?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, mobilesdk, mobilepush

I am looking at how my organisation can:

1. Send push notifications to a mobile app
2. Extend an existing web app (built in Drupal with some Node JS) to receive the same notifications as the mobile app (this doesn't necessarily need to be a push notification, it could be pulling data based on what has been sent/received to the user's mobile device).
3. The mobile app notifications and web notifications must sync, i.e. if a notification within the app is dismissed then this should happen in parallel with the web version and vice versa.

This must all be built into various journeys via the SFMC journey builder.

Number 1 above is straight forward, use the Mobile Push SDK.
It's number 2 and 3 I'm not clear on.

Number 2 - SFMC doesn't support a web notification push channel ([Is it possible to send a push notification from SFMC to a Web App?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274648/is-it-possible-to-send-a-push-notification-from-sfmc-to-a-web-app)) (although I believe the SFMC Urban Airship plug-in does support web push notifications to web apps).  Maybe there is a SFMC API the web app could call to retrieve all of the user's mobile notifications sent (and not yet dismissed by the user) when the user clicks on the web apps notifications page?

Number 3 - Is there an API that both the web app and mobile app can access to see which notifications have been sent to the user and clicked on, so that the apps can stay in sync?  I've looked at various API listed on the SFMC site, API specifics would be helpful here.

Given we have very little expertise within the SFMC development arena (it's more .NET, Drupal and Node JS and SFMC admin/configuration) I would greatly appreciate any ideas in how we could build out 2 and 3 as this is proving challenging at the code level.

Many thanks,

Lee